# Javascript Library - Mobile Touch - Draggable Objects on axis without disabling scroll

Tags: javascript, mobile, slider, touch, draggable

I have a page with a slider carousel. Recently, I've been tasked with adding touch interfacing to explore the slides by finger swiping.

I located an older jQuery plugin which appears to be no-longer supported. It allowed for touch sliding, as required, but it disabled the ability to scroll the page with a vertical swipe if the swipe originated within the slider carousel element's boundaries.

Does anyone have a resource for an element draggable library that allows to a specified axis (horizontal, for example) that won't disable vertical scrolling intentions if the origin of the swipe occurs within the element? This should function across devices like iPhone, Blackberry OS 5+

engadget.com has a slider on their mobile website that accomplishes this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple [jQuery gesture plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+gestures), that may help you out. You could easily integrate one of these into a custom slider plugin.